# Can i use reference of implementing class into method declared in Interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I have seen some classes desinged in a way where interface having the declaration of method which having a parameter of its child class type (implementing class) like below:

Interface A defined as has the method setData which has parameter of type AAbstract which is subclass of concrete class AImpl which implements interface A:

```
 public interface A{    
        void setData(AAbstract ref);
    }
```

where we have implementing class AImpl:

```
 public class AImpl implements A {
    private AAbstract instance; 
        public void setData(AAbstract ref) {
            this.instance= ref;
        }
    }
```

and again abstract implementaion like:

```
 public abstract class AAbstract extends AImpl {
       public abstract void dummy(String msg);
    }
```

personally I do not see it as correct design want to know the expert comments from design perspective.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `AAbstract`.  You haven't shown why it might be a poor design choice.  In general I think there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @markspace I can see an issue. `Animal` is an abstract concept, but it doesn't seem needed to say `AbstractAnimal`. So the question "*When should we use hungarian notation?*" pops up, describing a consistency problem. Many professionals do use it, but many professionals used `null` before realizing it was a "*billion dollar mistake*". The poor design choice is being inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with this kind of pattern is coupling - class `AImpl` and abstract class `AAbstract` are tightly coupled and circularly dependent. Each level in the inheritance hierarchy is aware of the other levels so the potential for a change in one to affect the others is quite high. Normally, you would try to design classes which are not dependent on, or aware of, their children. There are exceptions, where the number of implementations of a class are known in advance and don't often change, but they're rare. In this case, the the circular dependency between `AAbstract` and `AImpl` suggests that they might as well be combined into a single class.

To be honest, I don't see what value the pattern would give. `AImpl` contains an instance of `AAbstract`, which extends `AImpl` and so also contains an instance of `AAbstract`... so is it `AAbstract`s all the way down? My guess is that there's a null at some level, and nobody likes null.

Comment: It allows you to [design by contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), which actually encourages decoupling. It's similar to how the `Graphics` class is an interface. Some would suggest using `IGraphics`, but others would suggest using more descriptive names for the implementations

Comment: @VinceEmigh There's a significant difference here from the `Graphics` class - the interface `A` depends on its implementor `AAbstract` which is itself an extension of a concrete class. That's not exactly textbook Design by Contract. For that you'd have an interface which only depended on other interfaces. The interface for `Graphics` is described purely in terms of primitives and other high level abstractions.

Comment: Interfaces are abstractions: you abstract required behavior into an interface. Abstractions are interfaces (contracts), but allow you to supply attributes common between impls, reducing DRY violations. As you said, `AAbstract` is an extension of an impl (it abstracts impl details), but what specific details is it abstracting? `AAbstract` does not describe it. It suggests there would only be a single abstracted implementation, suggesting the actual interface is simply there for easy mocking and forced design. (continued in next comment with example)

Comment: Imagine `DirectX` and `OpenGL` versioning. They would both require different attributes to be abstracted, which can be defined as `abstract class DirextX` with `DirectX14` being the actual impl. `AAbstract` does not give us enough information on what impl is being abstracted, making it a poor naming choice. It's not textbook DoC, but the idea is extremely similar. These designs were created to help solve problems, and if they are forced (with no actual problem to solve), they create more problems, such as naming. This is just based on what I've experienced, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's just not good design-by-contract. The reason that naming is a problem is that the object design is imperfect - this is much the same as the point I make about coupling. If there's something in an implementation that the interface needs to know about then there's a problem in how the domain is being represented. However many problems are solved by this mechanism it's just causing more problems. The more I look at this pattern the less I like it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be simply use more descriptive implementation names.

---

`AImpl` and `AAbstract` suggests that you are creating an interface for a single implementation. In that case, YAGNI applies and the abstraction is not needed. Abstraction allows for inversion of control, allowing you to specify different types of `A`. If there is only one implementation, the abstraction is pretty much useless. Of course that's simply in theory, since people create abstractions for easy mocking in tests.

Abstractions allow for different implementations. If you use `AImpl`, what would you name the other implementations?

You could instead use `ADefault`, which suggests it is a default implementation (if other implementations dont fit the trick, use a default), but this is still the same problem as you specified, just a bit watered down.

Ask yourself: "*If I had multiple implementations, what would be the differences between them? Why would I need multiple implementations?*". That'll help you find a more descriptive name for each implementation, allowing you to name the abstraction  `A`, then definine different types of `A` based on the reason for their existance.

Given an example of the use of `A`, I'm sure I could easily find better names for the implementation. For example, `Graphics` is an abstraction, `OpenGL` and `DirectX` are implementations. Both implementations exist for different purposes, and it's described in their names.